# How to remove nth character in string

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove a 0 in the following ID:

```
0100001
```

and have it output:

```
010001
```

I have tried the following but I keep getting NaN instead.

```
f2.Patient_ID = f2.Patient_ID.astype(str).str.slice_replace(5,'')
f2.head()
```

Comment: `slice_replace(5, 6)` You have to specify the end of the slice, otherwise it slices to the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

The best course of action is following the suggestion of @Barmar by doing:

`slice_replace(5, 6)` as you have to specify the end of the slice, otherwise it slices to the end of the string.

More in general, outside of `pandas` dataframes, you can use this helper function:

```
def remove_nth(list_, n):
    return list_[:n] + list_[n+1:]
```

this function works with most index-able containers including with strings.

Comment: From the example code it seems to be value in a pandas column.

Comment: @Barmar If so, functions from `pandas` can be used to apply this helper to all items in the column

Comment: Or he could just use the built-in `str.slice_replace()`

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, let me update my answer

Comment: Producing a list when given a string is probably not the best outcome.

Comment: @MarkRansom Now it is fixed, if the input is a string it will remain a string